# property 'filter' of undefined when in production, but works fine in local

Tags: javascript, angularjs, spring, rest, api

i am working with angular 2 front end which consume rest API from Spring boot. In angular project, i have file globals.ts which contain global development variable which can be accessed by all component. In my front end, i have component to search data base on Rest API (can be local or remote API depend on global.ts).

globals.ts

```
export class Globals {
//localhost or 21.222.54.400:8090
public static get server(): string { return 'http://21.222.54.400:8090'; }}
```

if i specified the server to localhost and it consume API which run from my local spring application, it works fine. but if i change it to remote API, it return :

```
error_handler.js:51 TypeError: Cannot read property 'filter' of undefined
at SearchPipe.transform (search.pipe.ts:11)
at view_utils.js:159
at _View_SearchpopupComponent0.detectChangesInternal (SearchpopupComponent.ngfactory.js:96)
at _View_SearchpopupComponent0.AppView.detectChanges (view.js:272)
at _View_MidrouteComponent0.AppView.detectViewChildrenChanges (view.js:298)
at _View_MidrouteComponent0.detectChangesInternal (MidrouteComponent.ngfactory.js:85)
at _View_MidrouteComponent0.AppView.detectChanges (view.js:272)
at _View_MidrouteComponent_Host0.AppView.detectViewChildrenChanges (view.js:298)
at _View_MidrouteComponent_Host0.AppView.detectChangesInternal (view.js:283)
at _View_MidrouteComponent_Host0.AppView.detectChanges (view.js:272)ErrorHandler.handleError @ error_handler.js:51
```

zone.js:140 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'filter' of undefined(…)

That is strange, because i can use rest API for another importance, except pipe.

this is my search.pipe.ts :

```
    import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';

@Pipe({
  name: 'search'
})
export class SearchPipe implements PipeTransform {

  transform(service: any, term: any): any {
    if (term=== undefined) return null;

    return  service.filter(function(service){
      return  service.product_name.toLowerCase().includes(term.toLowerCase());
    })
  }

}
```

this is my search.service.ts :

```
    import { Injectable }     from '@angular/core';
import { Http, Response } from '@angular/http';
import { Home }           from '../home/home';
import { Observable }     from 'rxjs/Observable';
import 'rxjs/Rx';
import {Globals} from "../globals";

@Injectable()
export class SearchService {
    constructor (private http: Http) {}

    private Url = Globals.server+'/product?size=2000';  // URL to web API

    getService (){
        return this.http.get(this.Url)
            .map(res => <Home[]> res.json())
            .catch(this.handleError);
    }
    private extractData(res: Response) {
        let body = res.json();
        return body.data || { };
    }
    private handleError (error: any) {
        // In a real world app, we might use a remote logging infrastructure
        // We'd also dig deeper into the error to get a better message
        let errMsg = (error.message) ? error.message :
            error.status ? `${error.status} - ${error.statusText}` : 'Server error';
        console.error(errMsg); // log to console instead
        return Observable.throw(errMsg);
    }
}
```

and in my component i call this method :

```
  getHomes() {
    this.homeService.getService()
        .subscribe(
            services => this.services = services.content,
            error =>  this.errorMessage = <any>error);
  }
```

and in templete i call `{{ service.product_name }}`

all of help will be highly respected. thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I get the point why this is happen, that is because to get data from remote API requires time to complete. I tried to wait a while before access the API, then everything run like it uses to.